# Python generate the ClientRequestException object for unit testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

For my `Python` application unit test, I need to generated the `ClientRequestException`  object, to test the failure condition. using the below code to generate the exception object, but getting the error message.

**Code:**

```
    from office365.runtime.client_request_exception import ClientRequestException
    from requests import Response
    e = Response()
    e.args = []
    e.response="hello"
    e.status_code = 404
    e.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    err = ClientRequestException(*e.args, response=e.response)
    print(err)
```

**Error:**

```
self = ClientRequestException(), args = (), kwargs = {'response': 'hello'}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientRequestException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>       content_type = self.response.headers.get('Content-Type', '').lower().split(';')[0]
E       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'headers'

..\..\venv\lib\site-packages\office365\runtime\client_request_exception.py:7: AttributeError
```

May I know the correct way to generate `ClientRequestException` object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the code:

```
    error = requests.exceptions.HTTPError()
    error.response = requests.Response()
    error.response.status_code = 404
    error.response.reason = 'Not Found'
    err = ClientRequestException(*error.args, response=error.response)
```

Using err variable we can `raise` Exception for testing.